# Unable to get Area and Range in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML5 and ChartJS. I seem to find two different type of declarations among attaching JS Chart Versions 1.0.1 and 2.1.1. Can you briefly explain on that.?

Also, I'm unable to get the stripes behind in this chart in my local copy, but appears in JSfiddle. 
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/u20cfpcd/
Why is that so ?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="Chart_v2.min.js"></script> -->

  <script>

Chart.defaults.stripe = Chart.helpers.clone(Chart.defaults.line);
Chart.controllers.stripe = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function(ease) {
    var result = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

    // don't render the stripes till we've finished animating
    if (!this.rendered && ease !== 1)
      return;
    this.rendered = true;


    var helpers = Chart.helpers;
    var meta = this.getMeta();
    var yScale = this.getScaleForId(meta.yAxisID);
    var yScaleZeroPixel = yScale.getPixelForValue(0);
    var widths = this.getDataset().width;
    var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.getDataset().backgroundColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();

    // initialize the data and bezier control points for the top of the stripe
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      point._view.y += (yScale.getPixelForValue(widths[index]) - yScaleZeroPixel);
    });
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateBezierControlPoints.apply(this);

    // draw the top of the stripe
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      if (index === 0)
        ctx.moveTo(point._view.x, point._view.y);
      else {
        var previous = helpers.previousItem(meta.data, index);
        var next = helpers.nextItem(meta.data, index);

        Chart.elements.Line.prototype.lineToNextPoint.apply({
          _chart: {
            ctx: ctx
          }
        }, [previous, point, next, null, null])
      }
    });

    // revert the data for the top of the stripe
    // initialize the data and bezier control points for the bottom of the stripe
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      point._view.y -= 2 * (yScale.getPixelForValue(widths[index]) - yScaleZeroPixel);
    });
    // we are drawing the points in the reverse direction
    meta.data.reverse();
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateBezierControlPoints.apply(this);

    // draw the bottom of the stripe
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      if (index === 0)
        ctx.lineTo(point._view.x, point._view.y);
      else {
        var previous = helpers.previousItem(meta.data, index);
        var next = helpers.nextItem(meta.data, index);

        Chart.elements.Line.prototype.lineToNextPoint.apply({
          _chart: {
            ctx: ctx
          }
        }, [previous, point, next, null, null])
      }

    });

    // revert the data for the bottom of the stripe
    meta.data.reverse();
    helpers.each(meta.data, function(point, index) {
      point._view.y += (yScale.getPixelForValue(widths[index]) - yScaleZeroPixel);
    });
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateBezierControlPoints.apply(this);

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    return result;
  }
});

var config = {
  type: 'stripe',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      fill: false,
      data: [65, 20, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
      width: [12, 4, 5, 13, 12, 2, 19],
      borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
      pointRadius: 0
    }, {
      label: "My Second dataset",
      fill: false,
      data: [80, 81, 56, 85, 40, 65, 20],
      width: [4, 5, 13, 12, 2, 19, 12],
      borderColor: "rgba(192,75,192,1)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(192,75,192,0.4)",
      pointRadius: 0
    }, {
      label: "My Third dataset",
      fill: false,
      data: [81, 56, 85, 40, 65, 20, 80],
      width: [5, 13, 12, 2, 19, 12, 4],
      borderColor: "rgba(192,102,75,1)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(192,192,75,0.4)",
      pointRadius: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 120
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed

```
 if (!(ease == 1 || ease == undefined))
```

Please check this code : http://jsfiddle.net/u20cfpcd/2/

The ease is getting undefined if not animation occurrs I think, that was the problem.

Comment: @AmithBhaskar please mark the solution if worked for you, regards.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks. Would it relatively simple to animate the area bg fill? So it fades in smoothly after the animation. Could it be done with css transition?